# Where to add subviews in a viewcontrollers lifecycle

Tags: swift, uiview, xcode7, addsubview

For me it make sense to add subviews in viewDidLoad, because it gets call when the view load, but i can't do that with my subviews. I have subviews which frame depends on another already added subviews height and width, and height and width is not correct before viewDidAppear. So i add my subviews in viewDidAppear, but viewDidAppear gets call everytime the view appears which is bad. So for my solution right now i add my subviews in viewDidAppear and when view disappear I remove the subviews in viewDidDisappear. Is there another way to archieve this without I manual removing subviews from superview.

Example

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        print(PercentageView.frame.width)
        print(PercentageView.frame.height)
        CreateInfoRecipeLabels()//Add subviews
        CreateCircleDiagram() //Add subviews

    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        //When view disappear deallocate subviews
        for view in PercentageView.subviews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

UPDATE - Tried this instead, but it is like it can't add subview before there is a frame?

```
    @IBOutlet weak var RecipeInfoContain: UIView!
var MinLabel: SMIconLabel?
    var Min = "15"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        RecipeInfoContain.addSubview(MinLabel!)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        MinLabel = SMIconLabel(frame: CGRectMake(RecipeInfoContain.frame.width/4 - 50, RecipeInfoContain.frame.height/2 - 10, 100, 20))
        MinLabel!.text = Min + " min"
        //MinLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        MinLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 11)
        MinLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        MinLabel!.icon = UIImage(named: "Clock")
        MinLabel!.clipsToBounds = true
        MinLabel!.iconPadding = 5
        MinLabel!.iconPosition = .Left
        MinLabel!.textAlignment = .Left
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two thoughts:

1. If you use autolayout to dictate the `frame` of the subviews, then you can add them in `viewDidLoad` and the autolayout engine will take care of sizing them appropriately.

   Just set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` for the subviews to `false` and then add the appropriate constraints rather than setting `frame` values manually.
2. If you really want to manually adjust the frames, you can add the subviews in `viewDidLoad`, but then adjust the frames in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Rob, but I tried to add subview in viewDidLoad and then set the frame with CGRectMake in viewWillLayoutSubviews, but the program crashes. See my edit question

Comment: Hmm. I tried it and it works fine: https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/8af2c98902e39a60e177. Looking at your code sample, you are unwrapping `MinLabel` in `viewDidLoad`, but you don't instantiate it until `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. The instantiation should happen before you try to do `addSubview`.

Comment: My bad. I forgot to init the subview. Thank you for your help!